# Perform a regex operation over files in directory

Tags: regex, perl, bash, unix, scripting

I want to replace instances of `<span class='i'> </span>` with `<i> </i>` because I decided I want to format my pages this way instead. So I have come up with this command:

```
perl -pe "s/<span +class *= *['\"]i['\"] *>(.*?)<\/span>/<i>\1<\/i>/g"
```

I could make it more elaborate but I really don't think there are instances of weirdly formed tags like `< / span>` or anything so I'll leave it at that. It does have a non greedy capture which is why I used `perl -p` rather than `sed`.

So this will output the correctly modified lines but I'm not sure about the best way to send multiple files through this command. What's the best way to do it if I want all of `pages/*.html` to have the `span class='i'` tags fixed? Does bash provide some provision for doing this other than a for loop?

Comment: So what is the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will iterate over all html files in `pages/` and do an in-place edit with your perl script  .

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in pages/*.html; do
  perl -pi -e "s/<span +class *= *['\"]i['\"] *>(.*?)<\/span>/<i>\1<\/i>/g" "$file"
done
```

Comment: It seems like you've answered my question by posting a lengthier way to do it. Wouldn't this work? 

`perl -pi -e "s/<span +class *= *['\"]i['\"] *>(.*?)<\/span>/<i>\1<\/i>/g" *.html`

of course, running this after `cd pages/`

Comment: @Steven to be fair, I do not use `perl` all that often so without trying I do not know for sure if the in-place option can take multiple input files, it very well may.

Comment: Could you edit your answer slightly? I think I may have downvoted you by accident, it won't let me take it back until you edit.

Comment: @Steven, `perl -pi -e "s/<span +class *= *['\"]i['\"] *>(.*?)<\/span>/<i>\1<\/i>/g" *.html` will indeed work fine. I would have Perl create backups of the files though, as in `perl -pi.bak -e ...`

Comment: @Mauritz that's really cool actually. Then I can just do a diff to check the changes. Isn't perl wonderful?

Comment: @Steven incase it ever comes up. GNU `sed` too has the `-i.bak` capability

Answer (score 3):

@Steven, as per your comment to the answer by @SiegeX, the following will work fine:

```
perl -pi -e "s/<span +class *= *['\"]i['\"] *>(.*?)<\/span>/<i>\1<\/i>/g" *.html
```

I would have Perl create backups of the files though, so change the first part to

```
perl -pi.bak -e ...
```

Comment: i commented on your comment on the other answer cause I read that one first :)